# Mongoose Custom Query Builders

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do something like this in Mongoose. Is it possible?

```
// defining schema:
Product.queryBuilder.category = function(category) {
  return this.find({category: category});
}

Product.queryBuilder.available = function() {
  return this.find({availableQuantity: {$gt: 0}});
}

Product.queryBuilder.recent = function(count) {
  return this.sort({updatedAt: -1}).limit(count);
}


// in controller:
Product.query.category('men').available().recent(10).exec().then(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no available solution, I created my own.

https://github.com/gberger/mongoose-named-scopes

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-named-scopes

Answer (score 0):

NO, this will not work at all.

1. You need to decide if you are going to be using mongoose instance methods or statics. If you are using instance methods, then you must first retrieve the document from your db. When you do that, you can call any instance method on it. And, inside all instance methods, you will have a reference to `this` which will be your document.
2. However, if you want to use mongoose statics, you will not have a reference to the document via `this`. Instead, you will first have to do a Model.find from within that static (or pass the retrieved doc to the static as a param) before being able to perform operations on it.

My suggestion is you make this a static, wherein you pass the static the query elements and the query limits and have the static do a Product.find with passed parameters and have it return to you the retrieved document in a callback or promise.

Comment: That doesn't work at all. `Product.query` is undefined, and if I define the query builder functions on `Product.statics`, I can't chain them...

Comment: oh sorry. I didn't check your code for compilation issues. I was just responding to your desire to chain queries and pointing out a flaw in it.

Comment: @gberger I updated it with some working code... let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: Finds are chainable here: `User.find({gender: 'male'}).find({age: {$gt: 26}}).exec((err, docs) => console.log(docs))` works as expected

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am now building a small library that achieves this and it is turning out nicely. :)

Comment: Any hints on how to test `User.find({gender: 'male'}) == User.male()`? (I want to compare the Query objects, would want to avoid comparing the results)

Comment: Oh that's cool that they are chainable. never knew that. :) I have removed that part of my answer. As far as your question, I don't think I understand. Are you asking how to compare the results of a find without actually retrieving the document first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115232/discussion-between-world-and-gberger).